# How do I view what command or executable a shortcut links to?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

In Windows 7's Start Menu, I have a link to IDLE. I want to find out what file this shortcut links to. Here is an image of it in the "Properties" dialog:
[image: shortcut file]

As you can see, there is no mention of what file it links to. I want to know what file IDLE executes from, but I can't see it. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

That style of shortcut is called AppUserModelIDs and it's a way for newer versions of windows to allow for multiple copies of the same program to be grouped together.  Many apps use it now, adobe reader, chrome, firefox, etc.  It's just a way to "clean up" the taskbar.  Task manager would show you what file name it loaded.

Oh I see your problem, you can't directly start pythonw.exe even though that's apparently what is loaded so there's more to it.

If you're simply trying to run idle without using that shortcut, you could make a new one, this shows how.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118260/how-to-start-idle-python-editor-without-using-the-shortcut-on-windows-vista

I used process hacker to see how exactly IDLE is launching and it starts by calling `C:\Python27\pythonw.exe` and then passing `c:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.py` as the argument/file to load.  It just loads a blank "new" file to work on.

The shortcut technically is `C:\Python27\pythonw.exe c:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.py` in my case.

Comment: Well, how can I see the information or data or whatever used by these new shortcuts?